# jQuery - refer to another class of the same object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my situation:

I've got a site that will cover 4 different subjects. I start out with 4 divs that each have the title of those subjects. For example,

```
<div><p> Physics   </p></div>
<div><p> Chemistry </p></div>
<div><p> Biology   </p></div>
<div><p> Math      </p></div>
```

When I click on the 'physics' div, I'd like another div to appear that elaborates on some physics problem or something. Another click causes the 'elaboration div' to disappear. I've got that working with one 'subject' here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yfrNn/2/

This is the jQuery code I am using to accomplish this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".phys").click(function () {
        if ($(".phys:last").css("visibility") == "visible") {
            $(".phys").css("visibility", "");
        } else {
            $(".phys").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    });
});`
```

I could write this function 4 different times, once for each of the subjects I'm using, but would like a cleaner solution. I am wondering whether I can declare all of the divs in the following manner:

```
<div class="subject phys"><p> Physics   </p></div>
<div class="subject chem"><p> Chemistry </p></div>
<div class="subject bio"><p>  Biology   </p></div>
<div class="subject math"><p> Math      </p></div>
```

And then have a certain click() function run whenever a "subject" div is clicked, have the code recognize which subject this particular div is referring to, and display the appropriate "elaboration div".

I believe I could potentially do this with subclassing:

```
/* CSS */
div.subject{}
.subject.phys{}
.subject.chem{}
.subject.bio{}
.subject.math{}
```

Any thoughts? Is there a distinctly better way to implement something like this?

**Edit**

Here's an updated fiddle, with the HTML roughly as it will be in the implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/yfrNn/6/

Comment: You can, but it would be better to instead use a data attribute in my opinion to store the target additional content element rather than a class,that way you don't have to parse through the classNames of the title element or have an if elseif elseif statement. Or, better yet, use an anchor tag since this is indeed a click event and store the id of the target element as the href of the anchor.

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML you'll be using, including the secondary text?

Comment: just posted a new fiddle containing the html

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.subject').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();

//use a specific class name like `insideDiv` for the divs that are inside your main ones instead of div.another below

if ($(this).find('div.another').is(":visible"))
{$(this).find('div.another').hide();}
else
{$(this).find('div.another').show();}
});
```